# Cordova - How to detect whether google maps app is installed

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, google-maps, cordova

I am building a hybrid app using cordova. I would like to detect whether google maps app has been installed on ios and android devices.

Before redirecting to google maps app i would like to check whether the app is acutally installed on device.

I am redirecting using following urls -

For ios : `comgooglemaps://maps.google.com/`

For android: `geo:0,0?q`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using **ngCordova** plugins. http://ngcordova.com/

Using **$cordovaAppAvailability** we can identify whether any app is installed or not using its URI Scheme. Detailed docs [here](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#AppAvailability)

For google maps URI schemes are -

Android: `com.google.android.apps.maps`
ios:     `comgooglemaps://`

```
$cordovaAppAvailability
    .check('com.google.android.apps.maps')
    .then(function(success) {
      // success
    },
    function (error) {
      // error
    });
```